# Where not exists X amount of times

Tags: sql

This is a tough one. I have a query that returns available appointment times if they do not previous exist. This works. However I only want to return them if they are in the table less than X amount of times.

For example: There is a doctors office with 3 doctors. Therefore for each hour in the day there are 3 available appointments. My query now is only returning for 1 available appointment. Any Ideas? I tried using COUNT but couldn't get this to work.

You can kinda think of it like: `where not exist @Xtimes`

Here is the query for retrieving the avaibalble appointment dates for only one doctor.

```
SELECT * FROM TimeScheduleTable WHERE
NOT Exists (SELECT EmployeeId FROM AppointmentTable
            WHERE EmployeeId= @pEmployeeId AND
            CONVERT(VARCHAR,AppointmentTable.ToDateTime , 101) = @pDate AND 
            (
              (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), AppointmentTable.ToDateTime, 108) &gt;= TimeScheduleTable.StartTime AND
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), AppointmentTable.ToDateTime, 108) &lt;= TimeScheduleTable.EndTime)
              OR
              (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), AppointmentTable.ToDateTime, 108) &gt;= TimeScheduleTable.StartTime AND
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), AppointmentTable.ToDateTime, 108) &lt;= TimeScheduleTable.EndTime)
              OR
              (CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), AppointmentTable.ToDateTime, 108)&lt;= TimeScheduleTable.StartTime AND
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), AppointmentTable.ToDateTime, 108) &gt;= TimeScheduleTable.EndTime)
             )
             )
```

Comment: whate engine are you using? (mysql sqlserver etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return them under certain circumstances WHERE EXISTS (no NOT) would seem like a good place to start.

You can then GROUP BY your column and implement a HAVING clause to restrict whether any data is returned by the EXISTS.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TimeScheduleTable 
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT EmployeeId 
                  FROM AppointmentTable
                 WHERE EmployeeId= @pEmployeeId 
                   AND ...
                 GROUP BY EmployeeID
                       -- Only return if there are less than 4
                HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3 )
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for your help! I was able to get what I wanted by using your code. I just had to replace the "<=" with an "=" for anyone else trying to do this.. Thanks again Ben!